# Conditions for being Custom Hook in a Function

Tags: javascript, react-native, hook

I am new to application development. Since I'm just starting out, I'm not very good with technical expressions. There is language support in my application. The user selects the language on the first screen. On the next screen, there is a text according to the language chosen. It gets this text with the following function (useLocalization). Can I say I wrote my own hook for this function? Or should the function have other capabilities to be able to say I wrote my own hook?

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { localizationSelector } from "../redux/LocalizationRedux";
import { deutsch } from "./Deutsch"
import { russian } from "./Russian"

export function useLocalization() {

    const language = useSelector(localizationSelector)

    switch (language) {
        case "Deutsch":
            return deutsch
        case "Russian":
            return russian
        default:
            return deutsch
    }
}
```

```js
import React from "react"
import { Text } from "react-native"
import { useLocalization } from "../../localization/localization"

const Screen = () => {
    const strings = useLocalization()
    return (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{strings.boxes_header}</Text>
    )
}

export default Screen
```

Comment: Managing translation with redux will be hard and result in complex code. have you checked `18next-react` library. it provides easy-to-use hooks.

You can check this article https://dev.to/ramonak/react-native-internationalization-with-i18next-568n

Comment: Yes, you can claims that.